# Is Hanzo's Ultimate Global?

Tags: overwatch

Question says it all.

I'm wondering if Hanzo's ultimate has any sort of range.

I've been told that it goes infinitely, without limitations.

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm looking of proof of some sort, preferably a video.

Answer (score 5):

Hanzo's Dragonstrike will travel across the entire map until it hits the boundary edges. It can, in fact, travel through a spawn room.

Comment: The part about it having no max range is incorrect.  I've had it stop directly in front of me before.  While its range is somewhat long, it does have a range even though I can't tell you exactly how far it is.

Comment: From memory, my teammates said that the shot was fired at the cart when it was going next to the building with the columns and it disappeared right outside the Attacker's second spawn room.

Comment: Do you have proof of this claim?

Comment: @Powerlord Is it possible that the enemy Hanzo died while the ulti was underway?

Comment: @npst Dying won't stop Hanzo's ultimate.  They'd need to change heroes.

Comment: @Powerlord I've seen a dragon fired from the Ilios Lighthouse point out towards the yacht in the background, and it went into the yacht before it disappeared. That is significantly further than the Dorado defend spawn to attacking spawn, so I'd say it's more likely that Hanzo fired off his ult then swapped heroes upon respawning. This is testable though, I'll set a reminder on my phone to try it out later.

Answer (score 0):

It is infinite in terms of range, and I can confirm by saying that I've seen a Hanzo ulting on Hanamura map from Point B into Point A and I saw it still flying after passing through Point A.

As a sidenote, Hanzo ult from spawn is rather effective if you're in a rush to deny overtime and if you're lucky, well you might get a kill or 2. (https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4musmh/friend_wanted_to_change_hero_so_he_just_randomly/)